# Aggregates vs Data Model

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Aggregate's are requested from the storage as a whole and treated as a single unit. It is advised do design small aggregates not to affect performance. And this part is quite challenging for me. Especially when it comes to persisting data.

I have an `Activity` with `DueDate` property. *Activity* has `Participants` which can contribute to `Phases` of the *Activity* but only before *DueDate*.
So each time user contributes to *Phase*, I need to check whether he is a *Participant* and `Now < DueDate`.
It seems like I do not need to load the whole *Activity* graph with every *Participant*, *Phase* and *Contribution*.

The same time I must limit *Phase* contents changes, if contributions to this *Phase* already exist.

In addition to that parallel transactions with contributions from different participants do not affect each other.

This gives me a hint that `ContributionToPhase` must be a standalone aggregate and probably reference *Activity* aggregate by identity.
Though I still have to load *Activity* aggregate just to get the value of *DueDate* property. And to be honest this worries me much.

Data Model is the following:

```
Activity
------------
Id
Title
Description
DueDate
....

Phase
------------
Id
ActivityId
Order
Title
Description
....


ContributionToPhase
------------
Id
PhaseId
ParticipantId
....
```

It can be seen that in Data Model there's no direct link between `Activity` and `ContributionToPhase`. If I designed it as Transaction Script, I'd create an ad hoc DTO carrying all the data (but not more) required to validate particular transaction:

```
ContributionRelatedDTO
    Id
    ActivtyId
    PhaseId
    UserId
    ActivityDueDate
    TimeStamp
    ....
```

or

```
PhaseContentsRelatedDTO
    Id
    ActivtyId
    HasContributions
    Timestamp
    ....
```

How then should I approach it with DDD paradigm?
Is it ok if I model *ContributionToPhase* aggregate as having read-only property *DueDate* which is stored in *Activty* table? Or is it a smell of wrong aggregate design?

Comment: Can the ActivityDueDate be changed? If it does then you already acknowledged the fact that the rule will only be eventually consistent. You may copy the ActivityDueDate to a Phase and then do something like `PhaseContribution contribution = phase.contribute(...); phaseContributionRepository.add(contribution);`. Use domain events to maintain the ActivityDueDate synchronized and you may issue compensating actions if a contribution is eventually identified as illegal. As for checking that contributors are participants. you may do that in the application service using an authorization service.

Comment: You can also make the rule par of the domain with something like thw following in the application service `Contributor contributor = participantService.contributorForPhase(phaseId, participantId); phase.contribute(contributor); //internally checks if contributor.phaseId == phase.id`.

Comment: @plax Yes, it can be changed and constraints only the dates of contribution. Is not copying DueDate to Phase an unnecessary denormalization? If I materialize Contribution entity with DueDate from Activity table (couple of joins) this becomes transactionally consistent. So we set value via one aggregate, but use it in another one. Sure, we can say that each phase can be viewed as having its DueDate independent of other DueDates. Then data model changes, but not the ContributionToPhase aggregate.Is not loading Phase implies also loading all existing contributions of different participants?

Comment: @vorininp Well, you may map to the Activity table as long as DueDate is read only from a Phase's perspective. However, to make it clear that this piece of data belongs to another AR and is not part of the consistency boundary I'd probably pass in a domain service `phase.contribute(dueDateResolver)` which would internally do something like `dueDateResolver.dueDateForActivity(this.activityId)`. You may also resolve the date directly in the application service and pass it on rather than passing a domain service.

Comment: @vorininp As for loading a `Phase`, why would it load all contributions? A `PhaseContribution` or `ContributionToPhase` is a separate AR. The `phase.contribute` method is just a factory for creating a `PhaseContribution` and to better express the ubiquitous language (phase contributions do not pop out from nowhere).

Comment: Also, do not forget that by using the ISP principle, you may implement the `ActivityDueDateResolver` interface on the activity repository.

Comment: @plax I thought about passing the service in method, but ihen it looks like a reincarnation of n+1 problem we have with lazy loading.

Comment: That's premature optimization. I really don't think that issuing more than 1 query will be a problem here. You are dealing with a single ContributionToPhase at a time. Note that I assumed that you are not using the domain model for queries.

Comment: @plax Sorry, didn't get what you mean by not using domain model for queries.

Comment: @plalx `"Can the ActivityDueDate be changed? If it does then you already acknowledged the fact that the rule will only be eventually consistent."` - If you access both the contribution entity and the due date under the activity aggregate, then it does not have to be eventually consistent. At least as far as I understand DDD. :-)

Comment: @voroninp I guess the meant CQRS.

Comment: @voroninp Let's check what happens when the activity is an aggr and the phase and contribution are entities. For example we have a scenario in which Jane sends a contribution to phase x, while John sends a contribution to phase y in the same activity. This will cause concurrency, which you have to handle somehow. If you version the activity, then the second request will fail. If you do not version, then it will wait for lock, so it will be slow. I have the impression that phase x and y are independent, so the activity is a too big aggregate in this case. You clearly need a smaller aggregate.

Comment: @inf3rno Agree with this approach. Viewing Aggregates as a mere transaction boundaries is more instructive comparing to not too small-not too large 'magically' chosen graph of objects. What is not clear for me is how elaborate repository can really be. In data model (!) ’AggrA’ references 'AggrB’, B references ’AggrC’ and for action of A some properties of B and C are needed. I'd create interfaces/resolvers of required values explicitly implemented by repository. So there are two kinds of queries: the first for Domain Model, the second for UI ore other external client.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this kind of issue with DDD and ORMs, try to implement some CQRS. I like DDD, but I don't think you should follow it with your full hearth, I think DDD is good to make us follow good practices, but keep in mind it's being improved every day by *gurus*, since it doesn't have solution for all problems yet.

For each **transaction**, we call it a command. To perform a command, we need a `CommandHandler` and a `CommandData`. I see a `CommandData` as it was a *DTO*. There, you put all stuff needed to perform said command. The `CommandHandler` is more like a small service, handling business login, therefore they belong to **Domain**. Let's create a simple example:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<T>
{

    T Handle(T command);

}

public class ContributeToPhaseCommandData
{

    public Guid ContributionToPhaseId { get; set; }
    public Guid ActivityId { get; set; }
    public Guid PhaseId { get; set; }
    public Participant Contributor { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivityDueDate { get; set; }

    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public string CommandResultMessage { get; set; }


    public ContributeToPhaseCommandData( /* mandatory data in constructor */ ) { }

}

public class ContributeToPhaseCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<ContributeToPhaseCommandData>
{

    public ContributeToPhaseCommandHandler( /* inject other services, if needed */ )
    {

    }

    public ContributeToPhaseCommandData Handle(ContributeToPhaseCommandData command)
    {
        // do stuff here, you might set some response data in the 'command' and return it.
       // You might send a DomainEvent here, if needed.
        return command;
    }

}
```

They usually are called by **Application Layer**, in response to some use case (someone contributes to a phase). The Application Layer, before delegating the call to domain (Command Handler), should check if the `requester` (aka. user or another system) has authorization for doing such action.

Now, how do we **get data to supply** a command? I think you shouldn't be enforced to load full aggregate if you don't need it. Load it only if you need it.

There are sometimes you have a heavy logic, which needs full agreggates, therefore you can put it inside domain model/entities. Although sometimes you have more complex logic, which you hardly could put inside models/entities and needs some information for many parts, and it's just **impractical to load heavy aggregates** when you don't need everything at all. This makes your model kind of anemic.

It looks you don't need the full aggregate to apply your domain logic for this scenario. I just think creating alternative `lighter` versions of aggregates is useless, unless someone proofs the opposite (I might be wrong).

I'd try to make things as possible as I could (*KISS*) in the Application Layer:

```
public SomeResponseToCaller ContributeToPhase(ICommandHandler<ContributeToPhaseCommandData> command, Guid phaseId, IPrincipal caller, IAuthorizationService authorizer)
{
    if (!authorizer.authorizes(caller))
        this.ExceptionHandler.Handle("Caller is not authorized! Shall we log this info?");
    using(var db = new ActivitiesContext())
    {
        ContributeToPhaseCommandData data = db.Phases
            .Select(p => new ContributeToPhaseCommandData()
                {
                    ActivityId = p.ActivityId,
                    PhaseId = p.Id,
                    Contributor = p.Activity.Participants.SingleOrDefault(part => part.Name == caller.Identity.Name)
                    ActivityDueDate = p.Activity.DueDate
                }).SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == phaseId);

        if (data == null)
            this.ExceptionHandler.Handle("Phase not found");

        if (data.Contributor == null)
            this.ExceptionHandler.Handle("Caller is not a participant of this Activity!!!!");

        data.ContributionToPhaseId = Guid.NewGuid();

        var result = command.Handle(data);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return new SomeResponseToCaller() {
            Success = result.Success,
            ContributionId = result.ContributionToPhaseId,
            Message = result.CommandResultMessage
        };
    }
}
```

This `ExceptionHandler` is some sort of class implementing an `IExcepionHandler` which should deal with application logic exception. They could be injected in the Application's class constructor. Actually, you could even send the `AuthorizationService` in constructor, and reuse it for every application call.

The purpose of not just throwing exceptions there, is to make testing easier.

Now let's talk about CQRS. Its purpose, briefly speaking, is to separate *Querying* from *Storing*. From [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html):

> …its heart is the notion that you can use a different model to update information than the model you use to read information. For some situations, this separation can be valuable, but beware that for most systems CQRS adds risky complexity.

One good thing this approach brings is after executing the command, you could delegate the call to a ***secondary* storage with denormalized data**, for read-only purposes. This secondary storage might not even need keys and relationships. It would be like storing your DTOs/ViewModels somewhere.

People argue we read data more than we store, so this allows you to store data in a state which UI's could read faster than ever, getting "ready to present" data. For each new change in a model, you could insert new registries other than updating/deleting, so it's faster and easier to get historical data, diffs, and other stuff.

It's up to you and your business to decide how much to store, the level of denormalization. Since nowadays **storage** is getting cheaper, you can think about storing more stuff in that secondary storage, since it's relevant.

It could also be another kind of storage, like NoSQL, cache (which brings us to cache invalidation), up to you. I'm not saying it's easy to implement this, we should define transaction level between these layers, and other stuff I can't remember now.

So I think **it's fine to store denormalized data**, since you use them for read-only purposes and be careful to make them synced with your Domain Model storage (maybe SQL with EF). I hope this helps which a sort of direction to reasearches about this topic, my examples had the objective to *suggest alternative solutions* depending on specific scenarios, you should try to combine good solutions, use CQRS when it fits, and *Aggregates* when it fits. Combining them is allowed until someone proofs the opposite (again).